# Can I copy by highlighting and paste by middle click on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I was using Linux for the last couple of years and I find it extremely useful to copy text by highlighting it as well as to paste by clicking a middle mouse button.

I'm using a Mac now and I wonder if I can achieve such behaviour on Mac OS X.

Comment: I cannot believe OSX does not do this  ... linux rocks in so many ways

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to make this available by (partially) disabling SIP. Like if there would be a way to make it *properly* work, all answers in this thread don't provide a solution to copy selected text to a different buffer, without cluttering the clipboard.

Answer (score 33):

I wrote a free little C program that does something similar to Gilligan's answer. Whenever you drag-highlight or double-click text, it copies to the clipboard buffer. Then you can middle-mouse-click in any window to paste it. It is called "macpaste" and on Github (https://github.com/lodestone/macpaste). It works globally for every program I use that has textual data.

In iTerm2, disable their middle-click in Preferences, otherwise you'll get double pastes.

Comment: This is AWESOME! So close. If it only had a separate buffer to hold the highlighted text separately from normally copied text it would be almost as close to Linux as possible. Nice job

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :-) Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: This works, however it unfortunately messes up with chrome/firefox/safari/anybrowser middle-click-link to open in new tab. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Doesn't compile for me - `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

Comment: Cool! I've added below in my .bashrc and it works fine (xterm is only where I miss it):
    case "$(ps -ef | grep macpaste | grep -v "grep" | wc -l)" in
    
    0)  ~/bin/macpaste/macpaste > /dev/null &
        ;;
    1)  # all ok
        ;;
    *)  kill -9 $(pgrep macpaste)
        ~/bin/macpaste/macpaste > /dev/null &
        ;;
    esac

The only one sad thing that I don't have middle button on my MM2 and don't want to setup that thirdparty stuff... Thanks @remik !

Comment: This would be so great if it would not beep on almost every click.

Comment: The problem with `macpaste` is that it breaks middle click for everthing else. For example, I cannot middle-click to close tabs in Chrome, or middle-click to open a link in a new tab.

Answer (score 20):

You can try [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) (legacy versions can be used with a free license available [here](https://boastr.net/)). You can assign custom trackpad, mouse, and keyboard events to trigger specific actions on a global or application-specific basis.

Here's my configuration to bind a three-finger tap to <kbd>⌘V</kbd> (as this is the global paste shortcut. Alternatively, you can select from dozens of other trackpad and mouse gestures to emulate the paste command.

[image: Screenshot of BetterTouchTool's Gestures preferences]

Comment: FWIW this only solves the middle-click; I don't believe its possible to auto-copy highlighted text without an additional command. (Except for apps that specifically provide the feature, like iTerm2)

Comment: And has anyone come up with a reasonable solution for that so far? I miss my select-wheelpaste SO MUCH!!!

Comment: This is crazy that you cannot get this behavior in the built in terminal between windows....ahhh i miss linux.

Comment: @Desphilboy The three comments above yours are primarily complaining about the lack of copy-on-select, which is not solved by your answer.

Comment: Only can be done in a terminal and my answer is specific to terminals . @KyleStrand

Comment: What you could do is have a gesture for copy and a different gesture for paste - which I'm quite happy with for my use cases - which is just quickly get at text.

Comment: @adamrmcd It seems it is free only for 45 days then you have to buy a license to use it.

Answer (score 17):

The macOS terminal can do copy/paste with two separate buffers:

1. The copy/paste buffer which is shared with all other applications. It can be accessed by <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
2. A separate copy/past buffer which is shared only between (macOS) terminals. It can be filled (copy) by dragging over the text by mouse, double clicking, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> double-clicking for file names (no <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>). The content of this buffer is pasted by the middle mouse button, by <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, or by <kbd>Command</kbd> + two-finger-click.

Comment: This will save me many headaches

Answer (score 5):

Create the following Automator service:
[image]

Assign it a keystroke, like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (something unlikely to conflict with anything). Then, use BetterTouchTool to assign that keystroke to the middle mouse button.

The middle shell script comes from [this fine answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40859/9388). The first shell script copies the selection to the clipboard, the middle script clicks the mouse at its current location, and the AppleScript sends a <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the contents of the clipboard

Comment: This allows copying while clicking on the middle mouse. OP wants to highlight to copy by highlighting and then *paste* with the middle mouse button

Comment: Is there a way to have both middle click to open new tabs in Chrome and this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

After highlighting text in the Terminal, I can middle-click to paste it back into the Terminal without using the copy/paste keyboard shortcuts. This does not seem to work when the text comes from other applications ie. I can't copy text from TextEdit and then paste into Terminal with a middle-click. I am running Lion and I did not have configure anything to get this default behavior. I'm not sure about other versions of OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way in general but some programs will accept the middle button as paste

e.g.

- Aquamacs - an OSX configured emacs
- iTerm2 - a replacement for Terminal

For newer mice/trackballs clicking the scroll wheel acts as a third button

Comment: scroll wheel = middle button (it is clickable on most of mouses nowadays).

Answer (score 2):

Select Text to be copied, then Drag and Drop your selection (White Plus sign in red circle will be displayed with the cursor). This will copy-paste the text.
You can Drag and Drop inside Terminal or between apps.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the Automator script suggested by Daniel. It did NOT work for me on OS X 10.10.

I was able to make BetterTouchTool (v 1.15), alone, work for some applications. Like this:

[image]

I did Left Mouse twice for several reasons. The first one usually only changes the focus to the new window, but does not position the cursor. Also, clicking in a text box usually selects all of the text, which is then deleted when something is pasted there. I usually want the original text to stay.

Gilligan

Answer (score 1):

The following Karabiner Complex Modification maps the middle mouse button to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and shift middle mouse button to <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>:

```
{
  "title": "Edit-related mappings",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "MouseButton3 to Cmd+v: Paste",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "pointing_button": "button3",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "pointing_button": "button1"
            },
            {
              "key_code": "v",
              "modifiers": [
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Shift+MouseButton3 to Shift+Cmd+v: Pasteboard",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "pointing_button": "button3",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "shift"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "pointing_button": "button1"
            },
            {
              "key_code": "v",
              "modifiers": [
                "shift",
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The following maps the left mouse button to perform <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> after selection:

```
    {
      "description": "MouseButton1 to Cmd+c: Copy",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "pointing_button": "button1",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to_if_alone": [
            {
              "pointing_button": "button1",
              "halt": true
            }
          ],
          "to_if_held_down": [
            {
              "pointing_button": "button1"
            }
          ],
          "to_after_key_up": [
            {
              "key_code": "c",
              "modifiers": [
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

> Behavior of using this rule is a bit delayed. With the default Karabiner settings, you'll have to wait a little bit after starting a selection and moving the mouse. Changing some Karabiner settings may help with this but may have other consequences (I've set `to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds` to `200` and `to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds` to `200`).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that, if the problem is, as it was with me, that you couldn't get stuff that was highlit in an X-Quartz window onto the clipboard, the secret to that is to highlight, then XQuartz menu-> Edit -> Copy.  That way, it is available for paste in every ordinary Mac OS app.

Answer (score 0):

In majority of terminals you can drag and drop the highlighted text or alternatively you can use:
 Shift + ⌘ + v

It will act like in Linux pressing middle-mouse button ( is a copy and paste together)