# applescript how to focus keyboard on menu bar 2

Tags: keyboard, applescript, menu-bar

I am trying to get the keyboard to focus the right menu bar (Bartender 3 has this exact same feature).
In System Preference, Shortcut, Keyboard there is a shortcut but it works only for the left menu.

I've tried some AppleScript but I am total noob.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (activate menu bar 2)
    end tell
end tell
```

this is with a shortcut from bartender 3. Basically get the focus on the first menu (on the menu bar on the top right) so I can move with the keyboard.

[image: bartender 3 shortcut example1]]

It could work if I click the menu with the mouse (so scripting applescript to click) but I believe that I need to know the position of the last menu or the name.
Since those menu dont really have an order they might change (they are created with Hammerspoon so I might delete them, change them etc.)

Sure I could just click the menu that is always there and move from there but I would like to know how to recreate Bartender 3 shortcut.

Comment: The `activate` _command_ only acts on applications, not processes and you cannot activate a menu by saying `activate menu bar 2`.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249606/how-to-code-an-applescript-to-do-a-mouse-click-on-a-menu-bar-item?rq=1 you can use this to click on an empty area or double click on an icon, either way you get focus.

Comment: Focus where in the right menu bar ?  You're targeting _SystemUIServer_, which is largely associated with `menu bar 1`, and not `menu bar 2`, even though its on the right-hand-side.  `menu bar 2` is where icons belonging to user-installed applications exist, such as _Dropbox_, or _Bartender 3_'s icon, even though they appear to share the same physical space as the system icons from `menu bar 1`.

Comment: I've added some other info in the post. but yes the applescript I tried is just what I could gather by looking around the web. I thought that menu bar 2 is the menu on the right and I've seen other using the`SystemUIServer` to click so I gave it a try.