# How can I use the TrackPad's force touch as copy paste function in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, trackpad, copy-paste

Since MacBook Pro 2015, Apple introduced the "Force Touch" in the Track Pad. When you click it in the Terminal, by default it gives you dictionary/Wikipedia search results.

I would like to change it to a "middle button"-like function as in Ubuntu: copy the selected text into the prompt, without passing via the clipboard and without the need to use the annoying <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> sequence. Any ideas?

edit: <kbd>shift</kbd>  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd>   does the part of copying without passing via the clipboard. now I need to have force touch doing this.

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21595/can-i-copy-by-highlighting-and-paste-by-middle-click-on-mac-os-x/30860#30860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai). This application will let you customize  actions based on trackpad gestures (including Force Touch).

Here is the action I have defined:

[image: 3 Finger FORCE Click -> Middle Click]

With this setting, I can select text in an application (this works well in Terminal and iTerm), and without explicitly copy/pasting, paste with a 3-finger force-click.

Comment: Interesting! This is a 1st

Comment: thanks I was able to assign <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to Force click. However it is not going as smooth as I would expect because I have to be very precise and concentrated in this click otherwise it will double-paste or change the selection :(

Comment: @NirO.  You may have to experiment with different gestures to find the one that works best for you. If you run into an issue where you want to use a simpler gesture, you can define it only in Terminal/iTerm so it does not conflict.

Answer (score -2):

That isn't possible. It would have to be an option built into MacOS Touchpad preferences.

Comment: Why is this? I see no reason it couldn't be handled by a third party utility or injected.

Comment: I have yet to see a third party utility or application control terminal so that it can recognize a trackpad function that isn't supported out of the box.

Comment: You should be able to inject one using mySIMBL.