# Linux like second paste via the third mouse button

Tags: keyboard, mouse, copy-paste

On Linux, probably in every desktop environment you can use the third mouse button to past a previous selected text.

How to achieve such behavior on macOS?

Are there any scripts or commands one can run on the start of the OS to be able do this?

**Edit: some moderator suggested some answered question, but the solution doesn't work for me. Perhaps it's because I am using Monterey in 2022 and the solution is from 2016 - so six years old and probably unsupported for many years.**

Comment: Note it is the window manager that Linux uses - X Windows that gives the behaviour you mention. Most others e.g. MS Windows, classic MacOS, Smalltalks don't

Comment: So it is not possible. This is disappointing. It is one of the features I used all the time on Linux.

Comment: Which specific answers to the old question have you tried, how did they fail? I would expect at least the BetterTouchTool solution to still work.

Comment: Those are old answers. Nothing worked. I am on Monterey - Macbook Air M1. Perhaps it is the M1 issue? Do you know where can I ask MacOS related questions? I don't think stackexchange is a good platform for that. Are there any newbie question allowed websites for new Mac users on the internet? This stackexchange website seems not a good place for that.

Comment: "Nothing works" doesn't give people here a lot to work on. This question has come up before and has answers which worked for other people in 2016. If you have tried them all, please add this (and the outcome) to the question. Maybe there is a typo in your code, or the configuration is wrong, or indeed none of the answers work anymore. Without you helping us by sharing detail, there is no way of knowning.

Comment: Having said that, I would be rather surprised if https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208091/9058 doesn't still work.