# How to test middle-mouse button

Tags: hardware, mouse, software, click, peripheral

I have a bog-standard Tecknet USB mouse.

I'm having trouble with my MMB when using Blender (3D). At first I assumed it was a software issue but now I'm thinking maybe its the button itself.

Is there a way I can test this out on something else? I need to be able to `click + hold + drag` in multiple directions using the MMB.

I can't think of any other app that does this.

I looked into trying to swap the MMB with LMB and test it that way, but can't find a way to do that either.

Just to note, the mousewheel itself works fine.

Comment: Mac doesn't have native support for a middle button, so you usually need either manufacturer or other 3rd party drivers. See this test - https://www.onlinemictest.com/middle-mouse-button-not-working/ My middle button doesn't register on here at all, & yet does exactly what my Logitech driver tells it to.

Comment: I recently wrote an answer that touches on this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458218/119271, but it links to what would be considered a duplicate question/answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I copy by highlighting and paste by middle click on Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21595/can-i-copy-by-highlighting-and-paste-by-middle-click-on-mac-os-x)